# How to make objects snap to a position in html5 canvas?

Tags: html5-canvas

I'm looking into making a jigsaw game using html5 canvas and JavaScript.  I have the images(pieces) in place, and they are draggable, but I'd like the pieces to act like they are on a grid so that when you click and hold while dragging an image it can only be placed on certain tiles within the 3x3 grid.

A similar question was asked on Stack before but the only response pointed to a drupal module and I'm not using drupal.  I found one more similar solution online that uses Asp.net but I'm hoping to solve this all on the front-end, and if I have to use some server-side code I only know PHP.

The renderGrid function for canvas it seems, just draws a grid, but doesn't make it functional for snapping objects to certain places.

Does anyone have clues on how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Use divide/floor down math when setting coordinates. E.g. to space x for each 24 pixels:

```
   var gridx = Math.floor(x/24)*24;
```